# Handling $q errors within ui-router resolves

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using UI-Router to resolve 2 promises using `$q.all`. How can I handle errors if either of the promises return an error? Depending on the type of error, I would like to return an error template.

```
.state('main', {
    // ...
    resolve: {
       config: function(Service1, Service2, $q) {
          return $q.all({
            example1Data: Service1.get().$promise,
            example2Data: Service2.get().$promise
          });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563042/angularjs-fail-resilence-on-q-all

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is listen to error event `$stateChangeError` and redirect the state to your error page. Something this:

```
angular.module('yourapp').run(function($rootScope, $state) {
    $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeError', function() {
      // Redirect user to your error page
      $state.go('root.error');
    });
  });
```