# $q.all() in angularJS

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I have a set of ajax calls that should happen asynchronously and after all the ajax calls are made, some function should be executed. I am using $q.all().then() for this.
The problem with $q.all() is that even if one of the ajax calls fails the function won't get executed. My requirement is to execute the function regardless of the success or failure of the individual ajax calls. How can I go about it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [AngularJS - fail resilence on $q.all()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563042/angularjs-fail-resilence-on-q-all)

Answer (score 0):

Using $q.allSettled instead of $q.all solves the problem.
Please refer to the following link for decorating the $q.all function

http://www.codeducky.org/q-allsettled/

Answer (score 0):

You can resolve a promise with another promise, which makes it possible for you to do something like this:

```
var urls = [...];
var promises = urls.map(function (url) {
    return $http.get(url).then(null,
        // error callback returns a new promise
        function (response) { return $q.resolve(response); });
});
$q.all(promises).then(...);
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/j4b7pxmt/

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code to implement this logic.

definition of GroupPromise plugin.

```
//create a group promise function.
var GroupPromise = function(){
    this.allPromise = [];
    this.successPromises = [];
    this.failurePromises = [];
}
//use this function to add promises which you want to resolve on success or error. 
GroupPromise.prototype.add = function(promiseToAdd){
    var promise = $q.defer();
    var self = this;
    promiseToAdd.then(function(){
        var args = angular.copy(arguments);
        args.push({state: 'success'});
        self.successPromises.push(promise);
        promise.resolve.apply(this, args);
    }, function(){
        var args = angular.copy(arguments);
        args.push({state = 'failure'});
        self.failurePromises.push(promise);
        promise.resolve.apply(this, args);
    });
    this.allPromise.push(promise);
}
//use this to resolve all promises. 
GroupPromise.prototype.resolveAll = function(successCallback, errorCallback){
    var self = this;
    $q.all(this.allPromise).then(function(){
        //all API calls processed.
        if(self.failurePromises.length === 0){
            //no API fails
            successCallback.call(self);
        }else{
            //some API fails
            errorCallback.call(self);
        }
    });
}
```

usage of GroupPromise plugin.

```
//create an object of GroupPromise.
var myGroupPromise = new GroupPromise();
//add API call promises to queue.
angular.forEach([1,2,3,4], function(){
    myGroupPromise.add($http.get(url));
});
//call for resolve all promises and pass the success and error callback.
myGroupPromise.resolveAll(successCallback, errorCallback);
```

Answer (score -1):

You have to use individual defers such as:

```
    var myDefer = $q.defer();

    myDefer.promise.then(function(result) {

    }, function(rejected) {

    });
```